# Выравнивание карусели по центру

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carousel

Столкнулся с проблемой выравнивания карусели по центру страницы.
Создал карусели отдельный контейнер, которому прописал стили bootstrap `col-lg-10 d-flex justify-content-center`
Но в результате элемент все равно остается смещен к левому краю сетки (контейнер с текстом имеет точно такие же атрибуты и находится по центру):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код секции, в которой возникла проблема:

```html
<section id="main" class="main">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <p class="head_line">Текст который тут будет</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/photos/photo2.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/photos/photo1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
     </div>
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Прошу помощи с выравниванием карусели по центру

Comment: дык, у тебя верхний `div` - `col-lg-12`. Сделай `div` с каруселью таким же. По идее поможет

Comment: Nikolay Gabaraev, в том и соль, что сама карусель у меня должна занимать только 10 столбцов, при этом быть по центру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас разные `col-lg` для текста и для карусели, как уже и сказали - соответственно, - используйте для нужного выравнивания/позиционирования  `offsetting` колонки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась оборачиванием блока с каруселью в отдельный блок, растянутый на все 12 столбцов:

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/photos/photo2.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/photos/photo1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не уверен в стопроцентной правильности данного подхода

Comment: Это костыль, не стоит так делать

Answer (score 0):

Хм....ну прям 10-ть столбцов я не знаю, но возможно получится вот так:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <p class="head_line">Текст который тут будет</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!--Тут твоя карусель -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: но. Вообще и сетка в 1-10-1 должна получится.